# HTML picture element not working in Edge or Firefox

Tags: html, image

This is the sort of thing I'm doing:

```
<picture style="display: block; margin:auto;">

    <source media="(min-width: 1080px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-1080.webp">
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-720.webp">
    <source media="(min-width: 360px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-360.webp">
    <!-- ios media -->
    <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-1080.jpp">
    <source media="(min-width: 750px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-750.jpp">
    <source media="(min-width: 640px)" srcset="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-640.jpg">
    <img src="imagesIndex\hero-images\centaurs-horn-crop-750.jpg" alt="Firenze, Harry Potter's divination teacher poses for a photo for my walking tour on Edinburgh's Royal Mile"  class="center-box"/>

</picture>
```

Wrapped in `<picture>` tags.  And it does not work, not even the fallbacks work.  Is there a work around?  Do I need to cut the alt text or something?  What can I do?

It's meant to work on both.  And the fallback is always meant to work (actually does in IE) so why doesn't it here?

It's a graphics rich site viewed on mobile, I need to use Webp whenever possible.

Site is here
[www.pottertour.co.uk/index.html](http://www.pottertour.co.uk/index.html)

Comment: Not sure if it solves your issue, but make sure you use forward slashes **`/`** and not backslashes in the paths

Comment: No that doesn't solve it sadly.  Grrr.

Comment: Is this viewport setting OK?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  What could block the <picture> tag?  Can't have a whole website not showing images for 7% of visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a possible problem because of the file extensions on the later `.jpg` images, a couple of them are marked as `jpp` instead of `jpg`.

Comment: Amaze Iota, thanks so much.  Must stop coding at 2am.

Comment: It also needed me to add this:  type="image/webp" to the end of each webp option.